# SQLITE fetch statement in Android not working

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have everything working in my DBHelper class except for my fetch statement. I get a red line under query. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public Cursor fetchAllItems() {
        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ITEM, KEY_PRIORITY,
                KEY_ROWID }, null, null);
    }
```

Comment: Which `query` overload are you attempting to use? I can't seem to find one matching your parameters.

Comment: I'm going off an example I found. I'm not too familiar with sqlite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are missing to provide some extra `null`. See below:

```
public Cursor fetchAllItems() {
   return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ITEM, KEY_PRIORITY,
          KEY_ROWID}, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

For more info, read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

Comment: because its the requirement of `query` method to provide other parameters like **selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy**, but if you don't want to provide those parameters (like in your case) then simply put `null` there

Answer (score 0):

```
public Cursor fetchAllItems() {
return mDb.query("", new String[] { KEY_ITEM, KEY_PRIORITY,
        KEY_ROWID }, "", null, "", null, null);
```

}

This will work

Answer (score 0):

```
public Cursor fetchAllItems() {
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ITEM, KEY_PRIORITY,
        KEY_ROWID }, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

You may also read the API reference [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) regarding database. You can see all the available functions there.